# How to sort activerecord query by specific prority by attached table

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, pg

When I try to sort using the "case" by the field of the join table, the following error is returned:

> PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY
> expressions must appear in select list

```
<Table1>.includes(:difficulty_level).order(difficulty_level_priority('ASC'))
  
def difficulty_level_priority(direction)
    "
    CASE
      WHEN difficulty_levels.name = 'first' THEN '1'
      WHEN difficulty_levels.name = 'second' THEN '2'
      WHEN difficulty_levels.name = 'third' THEN '3'
      WHEN difficulty_levels.name = 'last' THEN '4'
    END  #{direction.upcase}"
  end
```

But a simple sort by name works correctly. Like this:

```
<Table1>.includes(:difficulty_level).order('difficulty_levels.name ASC')
```

I tried pasting the select('"difficulty_levels".*') and group(< some columns>) after includes(). It did not help.

Comment: you need to add `references(:difficulty_level)`. By Default `includes` will execute 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to sort by the field of the join table, but the field you are trying to sort by is not in the select list. You need to add the field you are trying to sort by to the select list.